React Native - Converting Node.js Encrypt to crypto-js
I've this code for encryption and decryption written in Node.js, and it makes use of Node's crypto:
const crypto = require('crypto');

const ENCRYPTION_KEY = 'some-random-key-12345';
const SALT = Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'ascii');
const keyGenerator = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT, 1000, 48, 'sha1');
const key = keyGenerator.subarray(0, 32);
const iv = keyGenerator.subarray(32);

function encrypt(text) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf16le', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
}

function decrypt(text) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf16le');
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf16le');
  return decrypted;
}

// Example usage:
console.log(encrypt('some text to encrypt'));

I am trying to replicate the same thing in react native expo project's TypeScript using crypto-es, however, the output is always wrong. Here is my TypeScript implementation:
import { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';
import CryptoES from 'crypto-es';

export type CryptographyProps = {
  readonly text: string;
};

const ENCRYPTION_KEY = 'some-random-key-12345';
const SALT = CryptoES.enc.Utf8.parse(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
const keySize = 256 / 32;
const iterationCount = 1000;

const getKeyAndIv = () => {
  const key = CryptoES.PBKDF2(ENCRYPTION_KEY, SALT, {
    keySize: keySize + 128 / 32,
    iterations: iterationCount,
    hasher: CryptoES.algo.SHA1,
  });

  return {
    key: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(key.toString(CryptoES.enc.Hex).slice(0, 64)),
    iv: CryptoES.enc.Hex.parse(key.toString(CryptoES.enc.Hex).slice(64, 96)),
  };
};

export const useNewCryptography = () => {
  const encrypt = useCallback(({ text }: CryptographyProps): string | undefined => {
    const { key, iv } = getKeyAndIv();
    const encrypted = CryptoES.AES.encrypt(CryptoES.enc.Utf16.parse(text), key, {
      iv: iv,
      padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC,
    });

    return encrypted.toString();
  }, []);

  const decrypt = useCallback(({ text }: CryptographyProps): string | undefined => {
    const { key, iv } = getKeyAndIv();
    const decrypted = CryptoES.AES.decrypt(text, key, {
      iv: iv,
      padding: CryptoES.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoES.mode.CBC,
    });

    return CryptoES.enc.Utf16.stringify(decrypted);
  }, []);

  return useMemo(() => ({ encrypt, decrypt }), [encrypt, decrypt]);
};


Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

You use UTF-16LE in NodeJS/crypto code, but UTF-16BE in TypeScript/CryptoES code. Switch to the UTF-16LE encoder CryptoES.enc.Utf16LE in the TypeScript/CryptoES code, see sec. encoders.

Deep sigh... That was it.
